# Is there any safe way to use Windows Credential Manager's generic credentials?

Tags: windows, credentials

(note: VS Code is just an example, question is not specific to VS Code)

I would like to use Windows Credential Manager's generic credentials, say store git passwords when using VS Code, so I have not forced to retype them every occasion when I start VS Code and execute repository operations.

VC Code supports this via utilizing Credential Manager's Generic Credentials. However any process running in context of my Windows account, easily can retrieve those passwords... I do understand why is this, but wondering, if there would be something "owner application" kinda thing, so the application who stored the password, also have an application secret, and only that application can retrieve (in the user's context) the password.

**Question**

Is there any way to declare for a Windows Credential Manager's Generic Credential which application can access it? (so only the VS Code can access it, only if it runs in my user account's context)